# Are the children of your cousins also mehram like the ones of your own blood siblings?

Tags: women, hijab, mahram

My elder sister observes parda (hijab) strictly even from the children of our cousin. Someone told to us that they are mahrams as they are your nephews and Islam has declared them as mahrams, which a have brought up some confusion.

According to history we can find that the children of siblings are mahram and other with whom you don't have blood relation are non-mahram as we can find the example of Hazrat Ali and Bibi Fatimah.

So please tell me am I right that children of your cousins are not your mahram in accordance with hadith and the Holy Quran.

Answer (score 2):

Cousins are not mahram, and neither are their children. Children of cousins are not considered  (in the point of view of Islam) nephews or nieces. See [An-Nisa 4:22-23](http://www.quran.com/4/22-23), where nephews and nieces are explicitly described as the children of your brother or sister.

Answer (score 0):

Maharem (Mahrams) in Islam:

> Your father, brothers, uncles, your sister's sons, your brother's sons
>   and your father in law.
>
> Cousins or their sons are not Mahram.

Answer (score 0):

Are the children of your cousins also mehram like the ones of your own blood siblings?

Cousins are not considered mahrams and their children are also not mahrams.